# When would mysql_field_count() return 0 for a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, luasql

When I was using `luasql` to query a MySQL database, I met a strange error, which, appeared to be caused by `mysql_field_count()`'s unexpectedly returning 0 for a `SELECT` statement.

I have two existing databases A, B and the following lua code:

```
local conn = assert(env:connect(db, user, passwd, host))
local cur = assert(conn:execute([[
    SELECT A.field1, B.field2 from A JOIN B on A.id = B.id
]])
local row = cur:fetch({}, "a")
```

Now the code failed on the last line, complaining "attempt to index local 'cur' (a number value)". The documentation says `execute()` returns a cursor object if there are results, or the number of rows affected by the command otherwise. This is evident in the [source](https://github.com/keplerproject/luasql/blob/44f09077a9ed9e8454d21f3d21749ab80fadeb70/src/ls_mysql.c#L394) of `luasql.mysql`. The assertions in my code suggested that both `mysql_real_query()` and `mysql_store_result()` was successful. So the only explanation to the fact that we ended up with a number instead of a cursor object is that `mysql_field_count()` returned 0. But wasn't it a `SELECT` statement? Shouldn't it return 2?

Note that this issue occurs rather sporadically. But when it does, there are typically several instances of the same lua script running on the same box. I'm not sure this fact is relevant though.

Comment: Maybe if the resultset is empty.

Comment: I don't think so. `mysql_field_count()` returns the number of columns for the most recent query on the connection. It has nothing to do with the rows of the result set.